# Why is only one if statement output when I have put different ones for different conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, submit-button

I made a code that has some simple math problems. When the user has pressed submit the if statements would determine whether the text box is null or has some input. I put an if statement for that if the user got the question correct it would document. write correct and if it is null it would write not answered and so on. Instead of that, it outputs correct no matter if the text box is left empty or if they got the answer wrong. I know that document.write is frowned upon but I'm a beginner so please help me.

```js
document.getElementById("q1");
document.getElementById("q2");
document.getElementById("q3");
document.getElementById("q4");
document.getElementById("a1");
document.getElementById("a2");
document.getElementById("a3");
document.getElementById("a4");
document.getElementById("submit");

function check() {

 if((q1.value == 6084) || (q1.value == 6,084)){
  document.write("<b>" + "1. Correct" + "</b>");
 } else if(q1.value.length == 0){
  document.write("<b>" + "1. Not Answered" + "</b>");
 }
 else {
   document.write("<b>" + "1. Incorrect" + "</b>");
  }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Quiz1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align = "center">Math Test ✍</h1>
<h3 id = "q1">Question 1 : 78 * 78 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a1" type = "text" required>
<h3 id = "q2">Question 2 : (100 / 6) + 45 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a2" type = "text">
<h3 id = "q3">Question 3 : 87 + 123 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a3" type = "text">
<h3 id = "q4">Question 4 : 100 - 23 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a4" type = "text">
<br>
<br>
<button id = "submit" onclick = "check()">I'm Done!</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because `6,084` is not a valid number. Instead it's interpreted as the comma operator, essentially doing `if(084)` which is always thruthy.

Comment: To supplement to what @Bergi said, you the `.value()` returns a string, so you should use `"` around "6084" and "6,084"

Comment: @Bergi so if I still wanted to use 6,084 how would I do that?

Comment: @Love2Code  Just quote it - if you want to treat it like a string, make it look like one.

Comment: Okay now I'm using `if((q1.value == "6084") || (q1.value == "6,084")){
  document.write("<b>" + "1. Correct" + "</b>");
 } else if(q1.value == null){
  document.write("<b>" + "1. Not Answered" + "</b>");
 }
 else {
   document.write("<b>" + "1. Incorrect" + "</b>");
  }`

Comment: But It's just outputting not answered even if I put something in the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bergi's comment on the question gets at the root cause of this problem, so I'm going to take a stab at helping to solve it.

First of all, if all of these answers are going to be numbers, you should use [`number` type inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). That will prevent users from typing in non-numerical characters, which will mean you'll only have to worry about `6084` and not `6,084`, so you can go ahead and remove the `|| (q1.value == 6,084)`.

Secondly, I don't see you assigning the variable `q1` anywhere. Did you mean to assign the result of `document.getElementById("a1")` to the variable `q1`? If you did, then you need to assign it by writing `const q1 = document.getElementById("a1")`. If that still doesn't work, put `console.log(q1)` in the first line of the `check` function to see what it is exactly that you're working with.

Alternatively, if you want to keep your ids and variable names the same. use `const a1 = document.getElementById("a1")` and then change every reference to `q1` in the `check` function to `a1`.

Comment: @Idtcoop I've now updated it to this `const q1 = document.getElementById("q1");

function check() {

 if(q1.value == "6084"){
  document.write("<b>" + "1. Correct" + "</b>");
 } else if(q1.value == null){
  document.write("<b>" + "1. Not Answered" + "</b>");
 }
 else {
   document.write("<b>" + "1. Incorrect" + "</b>");
  }
 
}` It's still just outputting not answered. I still have the rest of the document.getElementById's but there isn't enough space to put them in this comment.

Comment: My mistake. You need to assign the variable `q1` to `document.getElementById("a1")`, like this: `const q1 = document.getElementById("a1");`. That will get you the value of the `input` instead of the header with the question. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

You need a check for validation for data you are providing from form and also count how many answers were given correctly by the user

```js
function check() {

    var a1 = document.getElementById("a1").value;
    var a2 = document.getElementById("a2").value;
    var a3 = document.getElementById("a3").value;
    var a4 = document.getElementById("a4").value;

    if (isNaN(a1) || a1 == "") {
        alert("Please answer question 1 or enter a number value");
    } else if (isNaN(a2) || a2 == "") {
        alert("Please answer  question 2 or enter a number value");
    } else if (isNaN(a3) || a3 == "") {
        alert("Please answer question 3 or enter a number value");
    } else if (isNaN(a4) || a4 == "") {
        alert("Please answer question 4 or enter a number value");
    } else {
        let count = 0;
        if (a1 == 6084) {
            count++;
        }
        if (a2 == 61.66) {
            count++;
        }
        if (a3 == 210) {
            count++;
        }
        if (a4 == 77) {
            count++;
        }

        document.write("<h2>You have " + count + " correct answer out of 4 questions</h2>")
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Quiz1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align = "center">Math Test ✍</h1>
<h3 id = "q1">Question 1 : 78 * 78 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a1" type = "text" required>
<h3 id = "q2">Question 2 : (100 / 6) + 45 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a2" type = "text">
<h3 id = "q3">Question 3 : 87 + 123 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a3" type = "text">
<h3 id = "q4">Question 4 : 100 - 23 = ?</h3>
<input id = "a4" type = "text">
<br>
<br>
<button id = "submit" onclick = "check()">I'm Done!</button>



</body>
</html>
```